# requested url not found with production setting in django

Tags: python, django, django-urls

My website runs with no problem when DEBUG is set to true. but i get requested url not found error when i run the server in production setting. the admin page is fine.

this is my project urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',

  url(r'^', include('photography.urls')),
  url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
  # url(r'^$', 'photography.views.hello_world', name='home'),
)
```

this is my app urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('photography.views',
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^albums/(?P<slug>[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/$', views.photos_by_location, name='photos_by_location'),
    )
```

For testing purpose, i added a hello world view and it gets rendered with commented line in project urls.py. so I guess my way of including app urls is not really good when DEBUG is false . Is there a way to include my app urls that works in production setting?

Any help would be appreciated. thanks.

Update:

tried `url(r'^/', include('photography.urls')),` with a `/` after `^`. didnt work either.

Comment: Neither "/" nor "/contact/" (with the end slash) work in production?

Comment: FWIW, I always specify my url patterns from *most* specific to *least* specific as Django will attempt to resolve the patterns in the order specified. It's possible that a pattern is short circuiting.

Comment: @DanielRobinson nope.

Comment: @Brandon what do you mean by short circuiting?

Comment: `url(r'^$', include('photography.urls')),` this row mistakes! Try to remove the `$` character!

Comment: Meaning that a url pattern that you're not expecting to resolve first is doing so.

Comment: @fish_ball you are right. that is a mistake. but i added it there when i was trying things. forgot to remove it. i get not found error with or without the $ character. sorry about that.